# Schengen US citizen traveling with Belgian wife

Tags: schengen, us-citizens

We’re entering Schengen by boat in Portugal this June. After one week we’ll fly into Belgium to spend a few weeks there before driving to France for 3 weeks then back to Belgium for a month and then we were planning on a week Austria and Croatia.
All my kids and I have a European passport (Belgium) but not my husband (US passport).

I read about these different bilateral agreements like for example Belgium and France have for US citizens.

My embassy plays stupid when I refer to the European Commission report that lists all those and I asked for the original bilateral treaty’s where to find them but no response.

Anyone know where to find those? Anyone used this?
The embassy only wants me to apply for residing in Belgium for my husband if I want to spend longer.

Comment: Are you going to exit the Schengen area together? If so, your passport and marriage certificate usually would be enough to overcome any overstay concerns.

Comment: How long are you going to be in the Schengen area altogether?  How long in Belgium?  Depending on how long the first "few weeks" in Belgium is, there is no need for concern.  Also, where did you read about these bilateral agreements?

Comment: This is the document that I’ve found referring to those bilateral agreements: https://op.europa.eu/o/opportal-service/download-handler?identifier=c067e92d-5a8b-11e9-9151- 01aa75ed71a1&format=pdfa2a&language=nl&productionSystem=cellar&part=

Comment: Yes we were planning on traveling together with our 4 kids. Looking into maybe traveling to Denmark and exit Schengen through there. It’s not crazy far from Belgium driving wise. Those bilateral agreements basically state the 90 days usually as a maximum to stay but some don’t have the 180 day reference period. This article explained more: https://www.nomadicmatt.com/travel-blogs/how-to-legally-stay-in-europe-for-more-than-90-days/

Comment: @Belgiumgirl The europa.eu link is broken

Comment: Maybe this one works better https://op.europa.eu/en/publication-detail/-/publication/c067e92d-5a8b-11e9-9151-01aa75ed71a1

Comment: @Traveller the corrected link is https://op.europa.eu/o/opportal-service/download-handler?identifier=c067e92d-5a8b-11e9-9151-01aa75ed71a1&format=pdfa2a&language=nl&productionSystem=cellar&part.  Belgiumgirl: How much time are you planning to spend in Belgium?  For the rest of the Schengen area, you have three months _per country_ under directive [2004/38/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02004L0038-20110616).  There's little point in dealing with the bilateral agreements except in Belgium itself.

Comment: @phoog We are spending 1 week in june, 1 in July and 4 in August in Belgium and wanted to stay 2 more in September. The other weeks will be 1 in Portugal, 3 in France and 2 in Austria. The document per country 90 days is that only when I’d be moving/living in a EU country (like officially having my address there) or also for traveling?

Comment: @Belgiumgirl it includes visits and other travel.  The English version uses the phrase "move to or reside in," but it's clear from the other languages that "move to" is a poor choice of words (French "se rend ou séjourne dans"; Dutch "zich begeeft naar of verblijft in").

Comment: @Belgiumgirl also consider flying from Brussels on Air France/KLM, Lufthansa, Austrian, etc., so you can be processed by another country's officers without having to drive. (I know the French honor the directive because my parents used to exceed 3 months in Europe every summer; my father was an EU citizen and my mother is not, and the border guards never gave them any trouble except for one time when they went separately to passport control and the guards noticed my mother's lengthy stay.  As soon as they realized she was with my father, it was the end of the matter.)